# Windows Server 2003 cross domain access

Tags: windows-server-2003, site-to-site-vpn, cross-domain

I have two networks; Network A Network B set up. Each on it's own domain Domain A Domain B.

I have a user in domain A who has moved her computer to Network B. I have a site to site VPN between Network A and Network B. The user machine is in network B can access domain A without any problems.

The user wants to access some of the resources on Domain B, i.e file share. How can I give the user permissions in domain B?

Answer (score 0):

If Domain A has a business relationship with Domain B, or some other sort of accountability/responsibility agreement in place, you can use a [Domain trust](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961481.aspx).